# How to make a bunch of elements not accessible from keyboard

Tags: html, accessibility, tabindex

For example i have two headers: static and fixed. How can I prevent keyboard user from navigating throw fixed header?
By navigating I mean using `tab`. You press it and then you focus on next interactive element.

```
<header>
  <div class="nav-wrap static">
    *bunch of buttons, links, etc*
  </div>

  <div class="nav-wrap fixed" aria-hidden="true">
    *same as above but in different style*
  </div>
</header>
```

I want second one to be never accessible and remove all of it's elements from tabindex order. How do I do that?

Comment: The bigger question here is why would you have two headers with the exact same information in them? If only one of these headers is visible at a time (which I suspect it is) then the simplest way is just to add `display: none` to whichever one you aren't using at the time. This stops all focus order, hides it from screen readers etc. Do you have a specific use case as to what you are trying to do here as I think you may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie you are right. Thank you. My fixed header was just translated out of viewport. I forgot that I can just set `display: none` to it. Thank you!

Comment: not a problem, I know the feeling you can look at a problem and easily overlook simple solutions! Glad that got you sorted, good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display:none;` helps in my case. Thanks to Graham Ritchie